# Can a batter be given out caught off second hit in cricket

Tags: rules, cricket

Say a batter initially strikes the ball, it lands near his or her feet, bounces and heads towards the stumps.

The batter is lawfully allowed to hit the ball again in this case to protect the stumps.

But can the batter be out caught off this second hit, say by the wicket keeper or another close in fielder, given that the ball has previously bounced?

I saw this nearly happen just now in an Australian BBL game.

Here’s the hit the ball twice law: https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws/hit-the-ball-twice

Answer (score 2):

The answer is “no”; from [Law 33 (Caught)](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/caught):

> 33.2.2.2 a fielder catches the ball after it has been lawfully struck more than once by the striker, but only if it has not been grounded since it was first struck.  See Law 34 (Hit the ball twice).